# How to move multiple tensors to the Cuda device concurrently?

Tags: pytorch

```py
policy_data, value_data, action_mask = policy_data.cuda(non_blocking=True), value_data.cuda(non_blocking=True), action_mask.cuda(non_blocking=True)
```

```py
rewards, regret_probs = rewards.cuda(non_blocking=True), regret_probs.cuda(non_blocking=True)
```

```py
return action_probs.cpu(), sample_probs.cpu(), sample_indices.cpu(), update
```

I am doing some RL work and am wondering whether it would be possible to speed up fragments like the above by launching the data transfer to the GPU on different streams before waiting on them together. Does PyTorch have any functions that would make this easier? I'd rather ask here before I dive into the minutiae of optimizing data transfers.

Comment: Seems like a micro-optimization, did you profile your code to check it really is an issue? [Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html) is an example of CUDA streams usage (scroll down until you see streams section) though.

Comment: I tried loading on separate streams and I did not find it to improve performance any.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like one potential solution would be to pack all of the data into a single tensor (though of course you'd likely pay a small cost due to unused elements within this compacted representation.) An alternative would be to store this compact tensor as a sparse tensor (no additional data, but slightly more memory consumption per value). You'd have to test between these two to determine which was more efficient for your use case.

Comment: I'd leave this as a last resort because messing with views like is likely to introduce errors, but it is worth considering. I was testing the algorithm on the CPU for a while now and I actually forgot that `policy_data` is actually a view of `value_data`. It seems I was transferring the same tensor twice. I'll go with your suggestion unless PyTorch has something more convenient.

Comment: Some tensors are more convenient to group than others. What should be done when one of the tensors is `int8` and the rest `float32`? PyTorch's [views](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) do not support changing the type when the number of elements is different.